# XSLT remove unwanted elements

Tags: xslt, xml-nil

I have XML

```
<getInquiryAboutListReturn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <inquiryAbouts>
        <inquiryAbout>
            <code>Code</code>
            <nameKk>Something</nameKk>
            <nameRu>Something</nameRu>
            <documents xsi:nil="true"/>
        </inquiryAbout>
    </inquiryAbouts>
</getInquiryAboutListReturn>
```

And I want to process it with XSLT to copy all XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="//getInquiryAboutListReturn/inquiryAbouts"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**How could I copy all XML without `<documents xsi:nil="true"/>` or without xsi:nil="true"?**

Desired output XML

```
<getInquiryAboutListReturn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <inquiryAbouts>
        <inquiryAbout>
            <code>Code</code>
            <nameKk>Something</nameKk>
            <nameRu>Something</nameRu>
        </inquiryAbout>
    </inquiryAbouts>
</getInquiryAboutListReturn>
```

Comment: Do you only want the <documents xsi:nill="true"/> to be ommitted, or all elements with @xsi:nil="true"? It might be helpful if you post your expected xml output.

Comment: I want to omit all elements with @xsi:nil="true".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This simple XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- TEMPLATE #1 -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- TEMPLATE #2 -->
  <xsl:template match="*[@xsi:nil = 'true']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...when applied to the OP's source XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<getInquiryAboutListReturn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <inquiryAbouts>
    <inquiryAbout>
      <code>Code</code>
      <nameKk>Something</nameKk>
      <nameRu>Something</nameRu>
      <documents xsi:nil="true"/>
    </inquiryAbout>
  </inquiryAbouts>
</getInquiryAboutListReturn>
```

**...produces the expected result XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<getInquiryAboutListReturn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <inquiryAbouts>
    <inquiryAbout>
      <code>Code</code>
      <nameKk>Something</nameKk>
      <nameRu>Something</nameRu>
    </inquiryAbout>
  </inquiryAbouts>
</getInquiryAboutListReturn>
```

**EXPLANATION:**

1. The first template -- the [Identity Template](http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=492) -- copies all nodes and attributes from the source XML document as-is.
2. The second template, which matches all elements with the specified, namespaced attribute equalling "true", effectively removes those elements.

Comment: He wants all elements with @xsi:nil = true ommitted, not just document elements.

Comment: If you add `<xsl:template match="@xsi:nil" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>`, this will remove all `xsi:nil` irrespective of true or false value